# Load a page bit by bit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a large page in Rails with lots of individual queries and chunks of rendered code, and I would like to speed up the pace at which all of this renders.

What would the set up be like if I wanted the page itself to render first, possibly with multiple spinners, each partial rendering as it can? I'm using JQuery and Rails 3.

Specifics on how to get this accomplished would be very useful for me - I have used simple ajax in Rails 3 for toggling values and rendering partials after a request, but I don't know how to render a page partial-by-partial with spinners on each. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with rails, but AJAX would be the way to go for this. You would load each section and add it the DOM (jquery.append).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each partial would have to have its own controller method so you can access it from a URL.

You could make a `PartialController` and each method would render a different partial, which could then be loaded into your page via AJAX.

Or, you could keep each partial associated with its controller/model and create a method in the controller itself.

Using jQuery to load into a div called `#myDiv` is as simple as `$('#myDiv').load(url)`.